# flock command in root cron won't execute

Tags: linux, debian, cron

I've got the following code in my `root` crontab on my Debian

```
* * * * * flock -xn /absolute/path/to/run.lock -c cd /absolute/parth/to/project && ./run >> run.log
```

But I see no `run.log` or `run.lock` files where I specify them. In fact, there's no evidence  the script was executed.

Running `ps aux | grep run` only yields that `grep` call.

How do I run the `run` script using `flock` in the root `crontab`?

Comment: You are not using `flock` to run `./run` because of `&&`.

Comment: @IporSircer What must I do to make `run` run?

Comment: `cron` isn't `bash`, you can't use `&&`. Wrap your commands in a script, and tell `cron` to execute the script.

Comment: @IporSircer What should I write in the crontab entry?

Comment: @waltinator that's misleading; you can use `&&`. The line is syntactically correct but practically meaningless

Comment: I prefer to use `[ "${FLOCKER}" != "$0" ] && exec env FLOCKER="$0" flock -en "$0" "$0" "$@" || :` at the top of the script, which locks the script file itself. You can find it in the man page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The command in the crontab line is not being parsed the way you expect.

The cron daemon will run the command using the shell configured for the user in question.

This first shell will see two commands, separated by the `&&` control operator. So the second command is executed only if the first command exits with a zero return code, indicating a success.

The first command is: `flock -xn /absolute/path/to/run.lock -c cd /absolute/path/to/project`.

The second command is: `./run >> run.log`.

The first command will create the lock file and run the command `cd` as a child process, i.e. in another instance of the shell. The `cd` command with no arguments will change to the home directory of the user, after which the shell executed by `flock` will immediately exit. This will amount to having no effect at all.

**Even with the pathname the `cd /absolute/path/to/project` command here would have no effect at all on the working directory of the `flock` command, nor of the second command executed by the first instance of the shell.** This is because the `cd` command only affects the specific shell instance it is run in, not its parents.

The `/absolute/path/to/project` is treated as an extra filename for the `flock` command, not as a parameter for `cd`.

Since the first command exited and did not report any errors, the first instance of the shell (originally initiated by the `cron` daemon) will now run the second command. As the working directory of that shell has not changed, it is still the home directory of the `root` user, so it ends up trying to execute what is effectively `/root/run >>/root/run.log`.

My guess is that you probably meant something like this:

```
* * * * * flock -xn /absolute/path/to/run.lock -c "cd /absolute/path/to/project && ./run >> run.log"
```

The quotes will prevent the first shell from splitting the command line at `&&`, and so the second shell (started by the `flock` command) will get the entire remaining command line, and so the `cd /absolute/path/to/project` command will be meaningfully executed before running `./run` in the project directory.